# 10th call of .net RIA service fails with 'Login failed for user...'

Tags: silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

I get this error only after 9 successful calls to same .net RIA service.
System.Windows.Ria.Data.EntityOperationException: Login failed for user...

The .net RIA service has NO EntityOperation methods, only the one ServiceOperation which returns an XElement.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with SQLServer authentication.
The problem only occurs if I use a trusted connection from the .net RIA service. Changing that to a SQLServer credentials connection, and the app can call the service as many times as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you're running out of WCF connections?  Are you failing to close your channels when you're finished with them?

I came across something similar a while ago in this post: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200127135108/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/marcel/archive/2007/05/01/112159.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that. 

But that wasn't the issue.
I dug around and found it was a SQLServer issue.
If i replace the prod SQLServer with a staging SQLServer in the ServiceOperation method in the .net RIA service, it works as expected.
So, it must be a policy issue or similar on SQLServer m/c

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with SQLServer authentication. The problem only occurs if I use a trusted connection from the .net RIA service. Changing that to a SQLServer credentials connection, and the app can call the service as many times as needed